# Find all pairs of integers $(a,b),~ b\ne 1$ such that $\frac{a^4-b+1}{ab}$ is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all pairs of integers $(a,b)$ such that $\frac{a^4-b+1}{ab}$ is an integer.

$b=1$ trivially gives infinitely many solutions as the expression becomes $a^3$. I am not able to find any more solutions. I tried Fermat's infinite descent to prove there are no solutions and got stuck... Also I have started reviewing Vieta's root jumping. Do I get some help on how to proceed... Thanks!

Comment: Some solutions, if that helps: $(1,-2),
(1,-1),
(1,2),
(2,-17),
(2,-1),
(2,17),
(3,-41),
(3,-2),
(3,82),
(4,257),
(8,17),$ 
$(8,241),
(9,-386),
(9,-17),
(14,-41),
(27,82),
(30,241),
(43,-386),
(64,257)$

Comment: Oh nice! you're setting the numerator equal to 0 is it

Comment: Nah, just a python script (e.g. $\frac{30^4-241+1}{30\cdot241}=112$). I'm at lack of ideas how to solve this.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can finish off the rest... (8, 17) also gives a nonzero integer

Comment: No, $(2,-1)$ makes the fraction $\frac  {18}{-2}=-9$.  Others as well do not make the numerator $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a start.

You need $a\mid b-1$ and $b\mid a^4+1$. Since this implies $a,b$ are relatively prime, this is necessary and sufficient.

We know that $b$ has to be the product if primes $\equiv 1\pmod 8$, and possibly one factor of $2$.

For any $a$ you need to find a $k$ such that $(ak+1)\mid a^4+1$. Such $k$ come in pairs.

For $a\leq 7$, $a^4+1$ is prime or twice a prime, so there are only the trivial solutions $b=1,a^4+1.$

For $a=8$, $8^4+1=17\cdot 241$, so $b=17$ or $b=241$ is a solution.

$9^4+1=2\cdot 17\cdot 193$, which has no non-trivial divisor $\equiv 1\pmod 9$, so no nontrivial $b$.

Comment: Why select this as the correct answer? It might be the best we can do, but it seems premature to select it until people have had a chance to try a bit more.